# invoke-command doesn't seem to work - Did I use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts correctly?

Tags: powershell, winrm, trusted

I am not sure if I used winrmcmd to configure TrustedHosts correctly

I am running commands in PowerShell from host_computer (part of workgroup)

```
$cred = Get-Credential -credential user
```

Prompt appears, and I enter in password

[image]

Then I execute a command so setup.exe will execute on remote_computer (also part of workgroup)

```
invoke-command -ComputerName remote_computer -credential $cred -scriptBlock {& 'C:\share\setup.exe'}
```

Error appears:

```
[remote_computer] Connecting to remote server remote_computer failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client 
computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the 
TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (remote_computer:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I follow steps according to http://pubs.vmware.com/orchestrator-plugins/index.jsp#com.vmware.using.powershell.plugin.doc_10/GUID-D4ACA4EF-D018-448A-866A-DECDDA5CC3C1.html

On host_computer I open command prompt (shift, right-click, select "run as administrator") and execute the following

```
C:\Windows\system32>winrm quickconfig

C:\Windows\system32>winrm e winrm/config/listener

C:\Windows\system32>winrm get winrm/config

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="remote_computer"}
```

On remote_computer I open command prompt (shift, right-click, select "run as administrator") and execute the following

```
C:\Windows\system32>winrm get winrm/config

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/client @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}

C:\Windows\system32>winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="host_computer"}

C:\Windows\system32>winrm identify -r:http://host_computer:5985 -auth:basic -u:user -p:password -encoding:utf-8
```

And I get the following response

```
IdentifyResponse
    ProtocolVersion = http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
    ProductVendor = Microsoft Corporation
    ProductVersion = OS: 6.3.9600 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
    SecurityProfiles
        SecurityProfileName = http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman/secprof
ile/http/basic, http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman/secprofile/http/spneg
o-kerberos
```

Now when I go to host_computer and execute

```
invoke-command -ComputerName remote_computer -credential $cred -scriptBlock {& 'C:\share\setup.exe'}
```

I no longer get any error messages, but when I remote into remote_host, I don't see setup.exe in the Task Manager. It's been more than half an hour, and I cannot find any evidence that the file executed.

How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Maybe try a simpler command in the ScriptBlock like `{"Test" | Out-File 'C:\Test.txt'}` and see if you generate said file on the remote machine.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, this command worked

Comment: @TheMadTechnician still puzzled over setup.exe though

Comment: Then the Invoke-Command is working, it's a matter of it not executing what's in the scriptblock. Perhaps check the event log and see if the system blocked the install? If there is no error or anything then the remote machine evidently thinks it executed the command successfully.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I am unable to find any errors on event log

Comment: You can try dot sourcing it instead of using the call operator. `{. C:\Share\setup.exe}`. Your alternative is to try and create a PSSession on the remote machine, connect to that, and run the command in that session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding TrustedHosts using wmirm.cmd (see OP), the following command works

```
invoke-command -ComputerName remote_Computer -credential $cred -scriptBlock {cmd /c 'C:\share\setup.exe'}
```

Comment: Adding the source machine to the TrustedHosts of the destination machine, and viceversa, did not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Along with disabling the firewalls on both the machineA and machineB, and executing `winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="machineB"}` on machine A, I could then call `Invoke-Command -FilePath c:\scripts\test.ps1 -ComputerName machineB`

this link was also helpful
http://pubs.vmware.com/orchestrator-plugins/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.using.powershell.plugin.doc_10%2FGUID-D4ACA4EF-D018-448A-866A-DECDDA5CC3C1.html

Comment: running the winrm command as you wrote it gives me a syntax error: `Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.`

Comment: `winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="machine_name"}'` works fine (need to wrap @{} with single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but it might help people who didn't find any answer. So, WinRM is something like SOAP web based Web API and when you want to work with this API in non AD environment you may face different security related problems. The first thing you should be aware about, is that you have to configure not only the server side but the client side too!

If, for example, you configure a remote machine to do not use HTTPS and add administrator's machine to the trusted hosts you have also to execute on administrator's machine (from which session is initiated):

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts <target machine>
```

to add destination (target) machine to the trusted list.

You can easily see that if the error is like the following: "The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is 
different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts 
" it tells you about **client side problem** ("WinRM client cannot process"). Also, in a situation like this, you will not see any TCP/HTTP WinRM related traffic between machines as a client doesn't start interaction and throws the error.